# ASP.NET WebForms: SelectedIndexChanged not firing in user control

Tags: vb.net, webforms, aspx-user-control

I have an aspx page, that shows a user control with a list of element as a dialog.

```
...
<div style="display: none" runat="server" class="cssForDialog">
    <uc:ucList runat="server" ID="ucList" />
</div>
....
```

Then the **ucList** control, uses another user control for create a user element, always as a dialog:

```
...
<div style="display: none" class="cssForDialog" runat="server">
    <uc:ucNewElement runat="server" ID="ucNewElement"/>
</div>
...
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowCreateDialog" OnClick="btnShowCreateDialog_Click" Text="Show" />
```

The **ucNewElement** have a drop down list

```
...
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlElementTypes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
...
```

With the SelectedIndexChanged registered

```
...
Private Sub ddlElementTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlElementTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
  Do something
End Sub
...
```

The problem is that the SelectedIndexChanged is not firing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about replace it with FetchAPI?

Comment: a few years ago, I used to something like this, but recently, I have gradually move this approach to Javascript/FetchAPI, which is more easier to control for the UI. Just an idea for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown does not have the event handler.

```
onselectedindexchanged="ddlElementTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"
```